# Getting Facebook App ID for creating an application?

Tags: facebook

Can you please explain the steps for getting Facebook APPID? I have to create an application use this APP ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [this section](http://facebook.com/developers) on facebook and register yourself and your application. You will get the appid in minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to opne this site but not find any registration page, i think now facebook has changed their view so i found this link that open direct page of registration [Regisration PAge](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/?action=create)

Comment: the link in this answer works as of the time this comment was made